# How to produce a sequence frequency plot for one single cluster within a cluster solution

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, traminer

I couldn't find a sufficient answer to my problem, perhaps someone can help here? (I am a beginner to R)

I do sequence analysis, the state space is n = 10 and the time space is t = 168 (months). I drew a sequence frequency plot for a cluster solution with 8 clusters. However, the plot is not really open to interpretations because the single plots are too clinched or too small resp. (see graph below)
[image]

I did the following procedures so far (very close to the instructions in the TraMineR-Help-document):

```
dist.om1 <- seqdist(neu.seq, method = "OM", indel = 1, sm = submat)
clusterward1 <- agnes(dist.om1, diss = TRUE, method = "ward")
cluster8 <- cutree(clusterward1, k = 8)
cluster8 <- factor(cluster8, labels = c("Typ 1", "Typ 2", "Typ 3", "Typ 4", "Typ 5", "Typ 6", "Typ 7", "Typ 8"))
seqfplot(neu.seq, group = cluster8, pbarw = T, withlegend = T)
```

I tried to reconfigure the margins but the result was always the same plot (the attached plot was done with the default settings). So I thought, instead, maybe I could draw sequence frequency plot for a single cluster within my 8-cluster-solution.
(in Stata-code, I would write something like for a single sequence index plot `sqindexplot if cluster8 == 4`)
However, I don't know how this is done in R. If someone has an idea how to get a prettier sequence frequency plot, i'd be very grateful! 
Thank you!
Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 8 groups you may need to reduce the font size of the axes labels using the `cex.plot` argument. For example:

```
seqfplot(neu.seq, group = cluster8, withlegend = T, cex.plot=.5)
```

You may also get better looking plots with the `border=NA` argument that suppresses the black border around the bars representing each sequence pattern.

Alternatively, if you are using graphic devices such as `pdf`, `png` or `jpeg` to create your plot files, try to play with the parameters `width` and `height` of the  functions.  The larger the `height` value, the smaller the text looks out.

To get only cluster 4, use

```
seqfplot(neu.seq[cluster8=="Typ 4",], withlegend = T)
```

(See also [How to identify sequences within each cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342706/how-to-identify-sequences-within-each-cluster) )

And if you want to combine the plots yourself using for example `par(mfrow=c(.,.))` you have to disable the automatic legend, and insert the legend manually with `seqlegend`, e.g.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
seqfplot(neu.seq[cluster8=="Typ 4",], withlegend = F)
seqfplot(neu.seq[cluster8=="Typ 5",], withlegend = F)
seqfplot(neu.seq[cluster8=="Typ 6",], withlegend = F)
seqlegend(neu.seq)
dev.off()
```

Hope this helps.